# What does the derived category of a derived category look like?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories, derived-categories

For this question to make sense assume that $\mathcal C$ is a semi-simple abelian category such as $\mathsf {FinVect}_k$. Then the derived category $D(\mathcal C)$ has objects chain complexes of objects of $\mathcal C$ and morphisms the usual roof construction. Because $\mathcal C$ is semisimple, $D(\mathcal C)$ is also abelian. So there should be no trouble passing to $D(D(\mathcal C))$.

What I want to know is, what does $D(D(\mathcal C))$ look like and is it useful?

Comment: $D(C)$ is isomorphic to the category of graded objects over $C$, therefore $D(D(C))$ is isomorphic to the category of bi-graded objects over $C$.

Comment: Seems like the derived category will again be semisimple so you keep getting graded objects in the input. That is: D^{(n)}(C) should be Z^n-graded objects in C.

Comment: Ah- Leo beat me to it